# Python select on Windows

Tags: python, sockets, select

I'm trying to listen for data on several UDP sockets using `select`, but I can only receive data when I bind to a specific address.

My receiver looks like this:

```
import socket
import select

def create_socket(port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
    return sock

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sockets = [ ]
    sockets.append(create_socket(12345))
    sockets.append(create_socket(12346))
    print 'Waiting for data...'
    while True:
        readable, _, exceptional = select.select(sockets, [ ], sockets)
        print 'SELECT RETURNED!!'
        for sock in readable:
            # recvfrom socket, etc...
        for sock in exceptional:
            print 'Error with', sock
            sockets.remove(sock)
            sock.close()
```

I'm testing this with an interactive Python console:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto("test", ('localhost', 12345))
```

When I do this, `select` doesn't return when I send data (tried both localhost and my public IP).

If I change `create_socket` to bind to `localhost` then select returns successfully when I send data to localhost.  It also works when I bind to my public IP and send data to that IP.

This is Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Am I doing something wrong or is there some limitation to the `select` module on Windows?  Everything works fine if I create a single socket bound to `0.0.0.0` and do a simple `recvfrom` - I only run into trouble when using `select`.

Comment: After you setup your listening sockets do you find them listed in `netstat -abn`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  `netstat -abn` showed those ports already open by another application.  I closed the offending application and everything works now.  I would have expected `bind` to fail in this case.

Comment: You told it not to fail in that case.